# Is there any way to determine current action (create or update) in office 365 add-in?

Tags: javascript, office365, add-in

[Based on link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/Office.context.mailbox.item.md) and following code checks for the presence of an item identifier in office 365 add-in. if item not then it creates the appointment item as a draft and if item exists then it assigns existing appointment id to item id. (because of async function for create and update, both operations it returns itemId property returns as null/undefined it is so confusing and can't utilizes as flag for identification purpose)

```
var itemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(result){
   itemId = result.value;
});
}
```

For update it works as expected and it doesn't create another appointment item.
So I want to avoid creation of appointment item. as I don't find any suitable flag or alternative option to skip this code of item creation (also I can't remove this as it required for update process).
So my question is, Is there any way to determine current action (create or update)?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question correctly, you are juggling with words: "create", "edit", "update". Please clarify the point. The code you have provided (if statement for ItemId) is exactly determine if the item from draft (you call it "edit" or "update") or new item (you call it "create"). I will help, but what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Slava thanks for reply, when I navigate from appointment to add-in, I want to know if appointment is new one(create) or already created(update). Above code helps me to find existing item id which I would use for update process and this is fine. But in case of new (create) appointment there is no identifier or flag to skip this code block or avoid creating draft, as my addin has code to create new appointment id. Hope this clears. [Appcompose mode you cann't access the item properties synchronously]

Comment: @Slava, when i was going through your reply on msdn, you mentioned ItemId will be null only if item wasn't saved into the store, but i never get itemId as null always get undefined for both cases (create and update).

Comment: All scenarios, I am the Organizer and running add-in in app compose mode

Comment: @Mpr what is the purpose to get ItemId? Are you using it to make EWS requests? Why are you saying that itemId is undefined after "saveAsync" call?

Comment: Yes, I am making office 365 API (EWS) calls based on item id, in case of update I make the changes and update it. But in case of create, I don't want to add-in to create item-id, my API will create new item-id and work accordingly.

Comment: Now, I hear you, I just don't believe there is anything to determine this. We have similar discussion over there:[Outlook JS Addin - Compose form - how to check if the event/message is saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259731/outlook-js-addin-compose-form-how-to-check-if-the-event-message-is-saved/43260042#43260042)

Comment: Anybody from Microsoft, can answer this question? when can I expect determining field/flag for create or update appointment?

Comment: Microsoft has updated the functionality, now it won't send email to attendees for new appointment and Introduced new BUG, now it sends email on existing appointment (by clicking on add-in) calling saveAsync function it sends email to all attendees. Can anybody help me to avoid sending email in case saveAsync call, in case of update appointment?

Comment: Manoj, you probably should post your observation again. Mark the question with "office-js" tag; there are a lot of Microsoft guys monitoring this tag. Hopefully it will sort out for you.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov, done thanks!! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539712/calling-saveasync-method-sends-email-to-attendees-for-existing-appointment