# Outlook JS Addin - Compose form - how to check if the event/message is saved?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way in the compose form of an Outlook Add-In (office.js) to check if the object behind the form (in my case a calendar event) is already saved?

Comment: Do you managed to get the ID in compose form for an already saved item, I am also facing the same issue want to differentiate a fresh opened meeting vs a saved meeting and I dont want to call saveDraft until meeting subject is entered(as it saves the meeting unnecessarily).

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had to change the logic of my integration because of that, so that I don't need that information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the ItemId; if it's undefined the message was not stored, and if it exists the message is from Draft. Please refer to  [Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/preview/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#itemId)

EDIT:
I don't want to delete the answer completely, because of the valuable input in comments from Tim Wan. Basically there is no way to identify if message was persisted on the Exchange and check for the ItemId doesn't work in compose forms.

Comment: Yes I checked that, but per documentation `The itemId property is not available in compose mode.` and indeed it's `undefined` all the time in compose form, at least in OWA

Comment: It will work for compose as well, we use this method to check if item was saved and if it's not we are saving it, get back ItemId and use it for EWS requests. Try to open message from Drafts and you will have ItemId defined, this means message was persisted at Exchange.

Comment: I'm not sure how Slava is getting the itemId from compose? That property is indeed not available on a compose item. (It is available on Read Mode). Slava, maybe you can share your code? The only way I know of to get the EWSId in compose is to call saveAsync. There is no current way to get whether or not the object behind the form is already saved.

Comment: @TimWan Yes, you are right, it always undefined. I swear It was working while back, well something changed. Sorry for misleading answer. I'll modify it.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk Are you trying to determine if an appointment just created or updating existing one? Or this is related to synchronization time for Outlook Desktop, when you use "SaveAsync" method, which return ItemId, but this message created in local store and not yet sync with Exchange?

Comment: Basically for both, I'm trying to determine is the appointment window is opened by "create appointment" or by opening an existing one. Also the possibility to check if the appointment is already in sync with Exchange would be nice, but I guess that's not possible.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk For me is opposite: I am quiet sure it is not possible to distinguish between creation of the appointment or updating (this question pop up few times on MSDN forums) never saw the answer; As the sync with Exchange issue, you definitely able to do. After "SaveAsync" method return you ItemId, use it in "makeEwsRequestAsync" and send the request with this Id for something/nothing. If you'll get back "ChangeKey" your Item preserved on Exchange (real IMessage), if return error "Id is not recognized", it is new MailItem and was not preserved yet. It will be in a few seconds (~20 sec)

Comment: @alekkowalczyk This is the original thread if you have any questions regarding sync time for Outlook in cached mode: [App for Outlook: EWS request failed with item Id returned by item.saveAsync on compose new message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a7417d1-8af8-453f-bce0-584b7f79b0c1/app-for-outlook-ews-request-failed-with-item-id-returned-by-itemsaveasync-on-compose-new-message?forum=appsforoffice)