# Calling SaveAsync method sends email to attendees for existing appointment?

Tags: office365, office-js

I just noticed following change related office js (in compose mode for outlook add-in),

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(result){..}
```

Previously calling saveAsync method inside Outlook Add-in was sending invitation email for new appointment or draft, could be due to recent fixes or changes now it won't send invitation email to attendees for new/draft appointment. But this change has introduced new BUG, now it sends email on existing appointment which was working fine previously.

Can anybody help me to avoid sending email in case saveAsync call, in case of update appointment, as my connector does the work of sending invitation?

Answer (score 0):

Manoj, there was indeed a recent change to behavior for new calendar items like you described. However, we are fairly certain that there was no change in behavior for existing calendar items - it used to send updates and it still does.

There is no concept of drafts in OWA calendar today, so there is no way for the user to make changes to an item and postpone sending an update. Because of this, we don't have a good story for this yet but we are looking into a solution to mitigate this

Comment: Hi Manoj, We are rethinking this behaviour. Can you kindly share the scenario for which you need this functionality? Thanks